# WhatsApp search wildcard not working as expected

Tags: search, whatsapp

I'm a huge <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> fan and use it anywhere its offered. Chat applications are a must. Some are really good, most are mediocre, and some are just... Well you know.

WhatsApp is decent but I can't figure it out. It works fine (most of the time) if you search for a full word. But as soon as you get "fancy" with it, it just doesn't.

Example:

- Search for "Smith"
- Finds: Smith

---

- Search for "888-212"
- Finds: **888-212**-4878

---

- Search for "4878"
- Finds: 0 Results (?????)

---

I tried all the usual suspects ("", *, %) but no joy.
 Has anyone else played with this meta demon and had any luck getting it to behave like a proper full text search?

I did find [this question over at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63936153/117259), but I think its referring to searching while in the Erlang programming language.